# What is the best method to call an arbitrary JSON server from .NET (Specifically Windows Phone 7)

Tags: c#, wcf, json, client, windows-phone-7

I have a server that I have no control over, it's JSON based and I've put together a simple proof of concept that calls the server using HTTPWebRequest etc and it works fine (if a little wordy since MS have removed all Synchronous I/O calls).

Is there a better way of doing this? I've been looking at WCF as an option but any stable and reasonably performant library should do the job. This is a new area for me so I'm a little unsure what the best practice is (or where to find it out)

Thanks in advance
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether it's the best method, but HttpWebRequest plus [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28VS.95%29.aspx) are probably the best approach using classes from the Windows Phone library only -- plus HttpWebRequest's asynchronous methods ensure that your code won't block the UI thread when performing network requests.

Comment: The forced asynch is kind of a pain but I think probably the right decision for MS to take

Answer (score 1):

Once you've written the http request code once, you can easily abstract it away for reuse. You've already done the hard part :-)

Comment: This is true, I was just wondering if there was a more 'modern' way of doing it using an exisitng framework rather than hand coding all the HTTPWebRequest etc. It's not very complex code but I like to do things the 'best' way if possible